# How should TestNG suite-files paths be configured on Windows?

Tags: windows, eclipse, maven, testng, command-prompt

I have a nested TestNG suite-files configuration that **works perfectly on Linux**, but when I try to run on Windows, the paths get screwed up and I end up with "file not found" exceptions.

The Windows file system structure is like this:

```
C:\MyProject\RootSuite.xml
C:\MyProject\subfolder1\ChildSuite.xml
C:\MyProject\subfolder1\subfolder2\GrandChildSuite.xml
```

RootSuite.xml looks like this:

```
<suite name="RootSuite" verbose="2" thread-count="1" parallel="false">
    <suite-files>
        <suite-file path="subfolder1/ChildSuite.xml" />
    </suite-files>
</suite>
```

ChildSuite.xml looks like this (using a path relative to "subfolder1"):

```
<suite name="ChildSuite" verbose="2" thread-count="1" parallel="false">
    <suite-files>
        <suite-file path="subfolder2/GrandChildSuite.xml" />
    </suite-files>
</suite>
```

When I run on Windows, it seems to throw the GrandChildSuite.xml's relative path back to the root of the project.  I get an error like:

```
Running TestSuite
java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
C:\MyProject\newfolder2\GrandChildSuite.xml 
(The system cannot find the path specified)
```

Again, this works fine on Linux/OSX, so TestNG seems to be able to support relative suite-file paths like this.  Also, TestNG is converting the file path separator from / to \.  So, that doesn't seem to be the problem.

I am launching TestNG using the Maven Surefire plugin.  I have tried both from the command line and from the Eclipse TestNG plugin.  Both show the same behavior.

I have not been able to find many examples of people using suite-files in a nested manner like this, so any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Nathan please try and see if changing the file seperator pattern from '/' to '\' works or not. also specify the path something like this "./subfolder/subfolder/.."

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Mrunal!  I will have my Windows colleague try this out (I personally don't have a Windows instance I can try it on any more).